# Единообразная установка ОС на нескольких физических машин?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, установка

Есть 5 одинаковых серверов где есть dvd, usb вход и сетевая карта.
Нужно на каждый поставить linux и одинаково настроить затем. 
Можно вставить диск и везде вручную устанавливать.

А есть ли вариант поставить это как то автоматически или по сценарию sh?

Comment: Поставить на 1 машину настроить, склонировать образ системы.

Comment: Что за дистрибутивы? Так как информации минимум, ответ: используйте [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: ubuntu 12.04. 
Ну интересует общий процесс, что предстоит сделать.

Comment: Данный дистрибутив не поддерживается давненько. Обший процесс, можно глянуть [тут](https://xakep.ru/2014/10/06/linux-in-corp/), как вариант

Comment: вариантов очень много. например, [файл ответов](https://www.debian.org/releases/etch/i386/apb.html.ru), или даже «с запасом» — централизованная конфигурация (тут тоже множество вариантов: salt, chef, puppet и т.д. и т.п.)

Comment: К вышеупомянутому добавлю Ansible

Comment: Ещё надо узнать вот что. На сколько часто тебе понадобится это делать? Если один раз в несколько лет, то это один сценарий. Если несколько раз в день - другой.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin
А есть решения которые бы локально позволяли управлять этими серверами на базе kubernetes? 
Просто локально хочу попробовать поднять у себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kickstart, кажется, то, что вы ищите. С помощью него можно описать параметры автоматической установки.

- [Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html)
- [Аналогичный вопрос на askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)
- [Пример конфигурации](https://gist.github.com/ludo/3652811)
- [Статья на Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility)